# How can I install pip for Python2.7 in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, ubuntu-20.04

Is there any way that I can install "pip" for "Python2.7" ?
I could install python2.7 by

```
sudo apt install python2-minimal
```

I tried installing pip for this.

```
sudo apt install python-pip / python2-pip / python2.7-pip
```

but none worked. Can anybody have solution for this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Pip for Python 2 is not included in the Ubuntu 20.04 repositories.

Try [this guide](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-pip-on-ubuntu-20.04/) which suggests to fetch a Python 2.7 compatible `get_pip.py` and use that to bootstrap `pip`.

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py --output get-pip.py
```

Comment: This is weird because after the instruction to download it (curl) I execute it as described but it results in an error message: `File "/tmp/tmp62UdRM/pip.zip/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60` and `sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")`.  So this is Python3 code, not Python2.  Further investigation showed that these f-strings are all over the place in many files in the ZIP.  The mentioned `get-pip.py` script might have dropped Python2 support completely :-(

Comment: This guide did not work for me in Python 2.7. Had to use this URL to download get-pip.py

https://bootstrap.pypa.io/2.7/get-pip.py

Comment: then the above guide has to be updated with the correct URL

Comment: The URL has been updated in the guide, works fine now, good guide, +1

Comment: Something really basic that tripped me up: it doesn't matter much where you store get-pip.py because it's throw-away.  After executing this script, I could see the commands it installed by `ls /usr/local/bin/pip*`

Comment: For those who are paranoid (like me) and don't know the Python ecosystem well (like me), `pypa.io` is the domain for Python packages, so I'm assuming reasonable trust in this case.

Answer (score 54):

Try this one:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py --output get-pip.py # Fetch get-pip.py for python 2.7 
python2 get-pip.py
pip --version
```

Comment: Why is it necessary to use `curl` with `sudo`?

Comment: What's the purpose of `sudo add-apt-repository universe` *after* installing `curl`?

Comment: Why is it necessary to use `sudo` at all? Hint: it isn't. The script will successfully bootstrap `pip` for the current user without a problem. I am using it for Mercurial extensions which can be installed via `pip`, since on 20.04 Mercurial is still based on Python 2.7.

Comment: I get this every time: /tmp/tmpoO3a0w/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:164: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip<21.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pip<21.0

Comment: The following worked for me.

`curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py --output get-pip.py`  
`sudo python2 get-pip.py`  
`pip --version`

P.S I am not good with markdown :P

Comment: I removed sudo from curl and the python get-pip.py execution.  Examples on https://github.com/pypa/get-pip don't include sudo for executing the python script.  given the nature of this script, sudo'ing could be dangerous.

Comment: You don't need to add universe

Comment: `pip --version` refers to python3. You should use `pip2 --version` instead.