# Installing brew pip to Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, pip, homebrew

I'm trying to install pip to Python 2.7. When I try to run this line of code. I need this to work because I am trying to install GS tools dataset that I will need for geostatistical modeling as a Geologist. The GS tools is only compatible with earlier python versions like Python 2.7 and below.

$ brew install brew-pip

I get an error message saying "brew-pip has been disabled because it is not maintained upstream".

Comment: Python 2.7 hasn't been supported anywhere for many years now, can't you use something more recent?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/gstools/ has wheels for Python 3.11, i.e. a current and very much supported version of Python.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65125295/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython-2.7%5D+install+pip